# Specific value in SQL with Regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to find a specific value in my SQL database.

Specific value, I want to find:

```
$USR_Id = 9
```

**Case 1:**
51,16,71,8,**9**,91,19,29,
My resquest must find 9 but not 19 or 29 or 91, ...

**Case 2:**
**9**,51,16,71,8,9,91,19,29,
My request must find 9 but not 19 or 29 or 91, ...

So sometimes, there is not a coma before (cause it's the first value), sometimes there's a coma between the Id I want and sometimes 9 is into another numbers like 91 or 29 (and I do not want them).

Here, the resquest I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `___Teams` WHERE `TEA_Members` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Don't use Regex, use FIND_IN_SET() - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Does Regex are slow? Or FIND_IN_SET are better for this job?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() is written specifically for this task; it was deliberately added to MySQL for exactly this situation, because MySQL's authors know that people don't normalise their data properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REGEXP '(^|,)$USR_Id_value(,|$)'
```